# JS function repeating

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, function, object

```
    const myLibrary = [];
    
    function Book(title, author, numPages, readStatus) {
      // Constructor for a book Object
      this.title = title;
      this.author = author;
      this.numPages = numPages;
      this.readStatus = readStatus;
      this.info = function () {
        return `${title} by ${author}, ${numPages} pages, ${readStatus}`;
      };
    }
    
    function addBookToLibrary(title, author, numPages, readStatus) {
      // Add a new book object to array
      const newBook = new Book(title, author, numPages, readStatus);
      myLibrary.push(newBook);
    }
    
    function deleteBooks(index) {
      // Remove book from array at provided index
      myLibrary.splice(index, 1);
    }
    
    function displayBooks(arr) {
      // Iterate array and display the object to the page
      const mainContainer = document.querySelector(".main-container");
      mainContainer.innerHTML = "";
    
      for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        const div = document.createElement("div");
        div.classList.add("book-card");
        div.setAttribute("id", `arr[${i}]`);
    
        div.innerHTML = `<span class="book-title">Title: ${arr[i].title}</span>
          <span class="book-author">Author: ${arr[i].author}</span>
          <span class="book-pages">Pages: ${arr[i].numPages}</span>
          <div class="read-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" id="readStatus" name="readStatus">
            <label for="readStatus">Have read.</label>
          </div>`;
    
        mainContainer.appendChild(div);
    
        if (arr[i].readStatus == true) {
          document
            .getElementById(`arr[${i}]`)
            .getElementsByTagName("input").readStatus.checked = true;
        }
      }
    }
    
    function newBookForm() {
      // Displays a popup form to add a new book when the new button is pressed
      document.getElementById("newBook-form").style.display = "block";
    }
    
    function getFormInfo() {
      const form = document.getElementById("book-form");
      form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("Hi There");
        const title = form.bookTitle.value;
        const author = form.bookAuthor.value;
        const pages = form.bookPages.value;
    
        if (document.getElementById("read-yes").checked) {
          addBookToLibrary(title, author, pages, true);
        } else {
          addBookToLibrary(title, author, pages, false);
        }
    
        //addBookToLibrary(title, author, pages, false);
    
        displayBooks(myLibrary);
        form.reset();
    
        document.getElementById("newBook-form").style.display = "none";
      });
    }
```

**Edited with full code, I tried to be vague by shortening but now after comments and rereading I was just more confusing.

Also here is the form code from the html, since it was asked for:

```
    <form id="book-form">
            <h1>Add a new book</h1>
    
            <div class="book-formField">
              <label for="bookTitle">Title: </label>
              <input type="text" name="bookTitle" id="bookTitle" required />
            </div>
            <div class="book-formField">
              <label for="bookAuthor">Author: </label>
              <input type="text" name="bookAuthor" id="bookAuthor" required />
            </div>
            <div class="book-formField">
              <label for="bookPages">Number of pages: </label>
              <input type="text" name="bookPages" id="bookPages" required />
            </div>
            <fieldset>
              <legend>Have you read it</legend>
              <div class="read-radio">
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  id="read-yes"
                  name="readStatus-radio"
                  value="yes"
                />
                <label for="read-yes">Yes</label>
    
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  id="read-no"
                  name="readStatus-radio"
                  value="no"
                />
                <label for="read-no">No</label>
              </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div id="formButton-div">
              <input
                type="submit"
                onclick="getFormInfo()"
                id="form-button"
                value="Add Book"
              />
            </div>
          </form>
```

When the button is pressed on the page the entire function works fine the first time but each form works but also adds an extra empty form.  Just looking for any suggestions on where to look.

The form adds form info as an object to an array of objects.

Added a breakpoint at the function start and when skipping through the breaks, right after closing bracket for the arrow function it restarts the start of the arrow function.

Comment: You should include your html as well so we have a minimal reproducible example to test.

Comment: What is `formData` in `getFormInfo()`?

Comment: When and how are you calling `getFormInfo()`?

Comment: Unrelated to your multiple forms thing, but `new Object(formInfo)` is almost certainly not what you want. More: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Object

Comment: Can you update this to a [mcve] as a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/328193) which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: For `array.push(form)` did you mean `array.push(newObject)`?

Comment: Nothing in this code adds anything to the DOM. Maybe it's in the `// code here` that you left out?

Comment: `array` is not defined (in the code shown here), pointing to problems with global variables. Given that, Nick Gris' comment, mykaf's comment regarding `formData` and TJ. Crowder's comment about `new Object(formInfo)`, There are too many unknowns to give a definitive answer to this question.

Comment: What and where is `.main-container`?

Comment: Also take a look at *.getElementById(`arr[${i}]`)*: you have no elements with id starting with "arr."; I suspect it should be `.getElementById(arr[i])`; remove the backticks and `${}`.

Comment: And I can't seem to find element with id = "newBook-form"?

Comment: @mykaf `.main-container` is the <div> that is the grid container for the cards created and displayed, also there may be a better way since I'm new but the arr[${i}] is adding the index to a string to add it as an id attribute for it's specific <div> that is created to match the index of the array the book resides in for extra functionality later and ease of selecting.

Comment: Please update your question to show `.main-container` in context. Regarding `arr[${i}]`, there are no items with that id or even starting with `arr`; what element are you trying to target with this?

Comment: @mykaf the id in question is being created/added not selected. `div.setAttribute("id", `arr[${i}]`);`

Comment: I missed that; thanks.

Comment: @mykaf also if this is easier to see the full project https://github.com/Roc327/Library

Comment: Okay, I think the syntax errors are gone; where are you seeing an extra empty form? I'm noticing that the "title, author, pages, have read" at the bottom is repeated because it's looping through the entire `arr`/`myLibrary` each time, but `arr`/`myLibrary` is never reset.

Comment: @mykaf So when adding the fist object it seems to work fine, the second adds the object but then adds one with blank info like:  
`myLibrary =[ Book { title: "American Gods", author: "Neil Gaiman", numPages: 596, true }, Book { title: "Dune", author: "Frank Herbert", numPages: 894, false }, Book {title: "", author: "", readStatus: false }, Book { title: "Animal Farm", author: "George Orwell", numPages: "289", true }, Book { title: "", author: "", readStatus: false }, Book { title: "", author: "", readStatus: false }]`

Comment: How are you submitting a second time when you're setting  `#newBook-form` (which wraps the form in your GitHub) to style.display = none? I'm unable to recreate what you're saying; if I remove the `style.display = none` code, first submit shows the data I submitted; second submit shows that original PLUS the new submit PLUS the original again.

Comment: I think I found at least where it is at so I have something to look at now, I removed the code to get form data out of the arrow function which causes a lot of errors but actually works and only adds just the book object not the extras so I need to rework how my form data is submitted.

Answer (score -1):

Solved by removing the `form.addEventListener` arrow function then just leaving all other code in the `getFormInfo()` function.  This allowed me to move on and finish the assignment.  Thanks all.